# using setup_class for initialization "conflicts" with parametrize options

Tags: python, pytest

I have this file:

```
import numpy as np


class Variables(object):

    def __init__(self, var_name, the_method):

        self.var_name = var_name
        self.the_method = the_method

    def evaluate_v(self):
        var_name, the_method = self.var_name, self.the_method

        if the_method == 'Average':
            return np.average(var_name)
```

and this test file:

```
import unittest
import pytest
import numpy as np

from .variables import Variables


class TestVariables():

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        var_name = np.array([1, 2, 3])
        the_method = 'Whatever'
        cls.variables = Variables(var_name, the_method)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "var_name, the_method, expected_output", [
            (np.array([1, 2, 3]), 'Average', 2),
        ])
    def test_evaluate_v_method_returns_correct_results(
        self, var_name, the_method,expected_output):

        var_name, the_method = self.variables.var_name, self.variables.the_method

        obs = self.variables.evaluate_v()  
        assert obs == expected_output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Now, my problem is that I initialize the values (var_name, the_method) in the setup class.

So, when I use different values  in the parametrize, these values are ignored.

So, the test right now is done by taking as `the_method` value as `Whatever` and not as `Average` (which I want to have in the different parametrize setup).

Is there a way to deal with this without loosing the `setup_class`?

Because, if I ommit the setup_class, ok it works.

Comment: If I understood you correctly: you want to keep `setup_class` to initialize the object, but test parameters like `Whatever` and `Average` separately? Finally, you intend to have two tests: for `Whatever` and `Average`, right?

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk:Yes, I want setup_class to be able to initialize the Variables.And, I want to use `parametrize` to make my tests.I want whatever exists inside `parametrize` to be evaluated and tested.Right now `parametrized` is "skipped" and only what exists in the Variables initialization is tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can just limit the responsibility of `setup_class` method to a creation of Variables' instance with any non-throwing-exception data

```
@classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):            
        cls.variables = Variables(None, None)
```

and create tests

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "var_name, the_method, expected_output", [
            (np.array([1, 2, 3]), 'Average', 2),
            (np.array([1, 2, 3]), 'Whatever', 'whatever you want')
        ])
    def test_evaluate_v_method_returns_correct_results(
        self, var_name, the_method, expected_output):

        self.variables.var_name = var_name
        self.variables.the_method = the_method

        assert self.variables.evaluate_v() == expected_output
```

But personally, I don't think passing `None`s to the constructor is a very clean solution. I suggest making the parameters optional or creating Variables` instance every test.

Comment: Making the parameters optional? You mean the class initialization arguments?Or the parameters of th pytest.parametrize?And by optional you mean don't use them?The other solution, creating Variables in every test , will lead to many small test functions which is not good either.

Comment: @George I mean creating initialization arguments optional :) These arguments may be optional, but... it depends if they are necessary (object without them might have no sense and it will break your domain). And about many small tests - again, your object may be mutable or immutable. It depends on your concept and domain.

Comment: @George And by optional I mean `def __init__(self, *args)` or `def __init__(self, **kwargs)`